# Parsing data from internet in a Android App

Tags: android, json

Hey folks so here i am starting out with a few baby steps in Android Programming . i went through the relevant videos and feel confident to jump into the pool . My motivation is to make a simple app that gives the waiting time for my school buses at the university . The examples that i saw made using of JSON parsing to parse data from the internet specifically twitter . So how do i check if the website that i want to pull in information gives me such APIS or not . For example for a site like http://www.sbstransit.com.sg/ i see no APIs for parsing . So how do i go about in this case . This is just an example website .

Comment: Actully you want to parse json/XML API response in android??

Comment: @Rajnish : yes . How should i go about . Should the site provide me with APIS . If it doesnt how do i do it ? I am new so forgive if my questions sound stupid .

Comment: you have a api about ` http://www.sbstransit.com.sg/` scraping data?

Comment: @Rajnish : i dont think so . searching online for JSON apis for sbstransit does not give my anything . Though searching the same for say twitter i got a bunch of them . So do i need to do something diff here ?

Comment: yes i want the API . THe link of the tutorial you give below is very informational . I understood it . But isnt it based on the underlaying notion that the website will return a structured JSON object only . What if it doesnot ( seems to be my case :( )

Comment: can i know what JSON object which is return by website??

Answer (score 1):

Try out like ...

```
 String response = 'json string';
        try {
            JSONArray responseObj= new JSONArray(response);
                 String week_percentage_work = responseObj.getString("key");
             }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

More information please visit : [android-json-parsing-tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

[stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210676/android-json-api-parsing)